# Is there a Legal term to put before a definition to describe a comma separated list of items (i.e. "collectively")

Tags: united-states, indiana

I have the following statement in a contract:

> I understand that as part of my job duties I may be asked to create or contribute to the creation of marketing materials, office documents, website content, computer programs, documentation or other copyrightable materials (“Work Product”)

I would like to make it clear that the definition of "Work Product" applies to the entire comma separated list of items not just "other copyrightable materials".  What's the best way to do that?

In the US > Indiana.

Comment: "Collectively" works fine and I have seen it used that way. Ultimately, any wording that conveys the meaning clearly is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a single term with the meaning you want, but the same result is easily achieved with a little rewriting:

> I understand that as part of my job duties I may be asked to create or contribute to the creation of “Work Product”, which includes: marketing materials, office documents, website content, computer programs, documentation, or other copyrightable materials.